# Google app engine No module named appengine.api

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Deploying python app engine project.
It works when I deploy locally in a virtual environment, but when deploying to google app engine I get an error (in the terminal):

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

I can import google, but I cannot import google.appengine o r anything inside it.

my app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2
threadsafe: true
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.12.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
numpy==1.12.1
scipy==0.19.0
Pillow==4.1.1
scikit_learn==0.17
python-dateutil
webapp2==3.0.0b1
google-cloud-storage==1.1.1
pycrypto==2.6
google-api-python-client==1.5.0
```

How do I solve this issue?

Edit:
Additional info: 
Google Cloud SDK 158.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.54
deploying from macOS

Comment: Any progress so far?